# Need to stop mysql when repair table?

Tags: mysql, repair

I want to know that, When we do the `mysqlcheck` or `myisamchk` that time  we need to stop the mysql `/etc/init.d/mysql stop` or no need?

```
myisamchk -r /var/lib/mysql/sample/*.MYI
```

Comment: Please improve your question. Not very clear

Answer (score 0):

Yes,Sorry I get it by search.

Answer: mysqlcheck must be used when the mysqld server is running, whereas myisamchk should be used when it is not